# rdlc report spliting amount into rupees & Paise

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am using an RDLC report. In that I have an field for amount. I need to split that amount in Rupees and Paise in two different Textbox or Expression and I need to have amount in words function for total amount with rupees and Paise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the question is? What you do so far? Show an expression or describe what you done.

Comment: For example I have an amount which is 631.50 in Rdlc i need to show as 631 in one text field and .50 in another text field.

Comment: I undesrtand, but your question sounds too broad and can be closed. It sound like I need to do that - how to do it. You need to try to solve problem for yourself and if you have troubles - then ask with details - what do you do up to now. In general you can split string with amount using separator. So you can have 631.50 - you can convert to string and split using `.`. Then you can show first part inside first text box and second inside second. As a result you can have: `|631| ru |50| p`.